# Реализация поиска пользователей

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, api, search

Есть API которое выдает список пользователей с N количеством параметров у пользователя(имя, телефон...). Необходимо реализовать поиск пользователя по совпадению с любым полем пользователя.

Сайт на PHP Laravel с Vue Vuetify.

На странице выводится список всех пользователей но с пагинацией так как кол-во пользователей более 50 000, то есть во Vue храниться пользователи для конкретной одной страницы. При переходе на следующую происходит новый запрос к серверу. *(это правильная реализация для максимальной скорости работы с большим кол вом пользователей?)*

Вопрос следующий где будет более правильно и каким способом будет работать быстрее, реализовать поиск пользователей по всех их полям.

1. Хранить всех пользователей в массиве внутри Vue и на изменение поля поиска делать по нему фильтрацию. (но мне кажется такой вариант не подходит для большого кол-ва пользователей)
2. При изменения поля поиска делать запрос к API где дореализовать метод поиска в БД

Какие есть еще варианты и каким способ это будет максимально быстро работать?

Спасибо

Comment: Разумеется, второй.

Comment: Самый быстрый - через сервисконтейнер

Comment: второй, поиск через `LIKE%`, у билдера есть метод `paginate`, на фронте обязательно используй `debounce` при вводе поисковой фразы. 50к оъектов на фронте - браузер офигеет. Можешь попробовать посмотреть на расход памяти в chrome dev tools. Пользователи айфонов и айпадов вообще не смогут увидеть твой сайт

Comment: Спасибо, большое!